# Is there a way for communicating between two asyncio loops that are under different threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio

I can't find an option for communicating between two different asyncio event loops that are under a different thread.

when I try to communicate and use resources that are part of a different asyncio event loop I get an error of:

```
got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

I've built a program which does background tasks on the server and also runs a Web sockets server.
Clients are connecting to the Web sockets server and then emitting events for the server to perform.
When the server finish to perform the emitted event he notify all clients and send them the result back.

[Diagram that demonstrate my program logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma5fD.png)

The server is running on a synchronized function.
The task thread is also on synchronized function.
The web socket server uses an asynchronized function (Websockets library requires it to run on asyncio event loop)

Therefore for now to achieve this goal I'm creating another asyncio event loop under the task thread.
I've created a shared lock between the Websocket server and the Task thread so I wont cause bugs by using the "Send" method at the same time.

The problem is that I'm getting the error of:

```
got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

When I try to use the method of "client.send" even though I'm using a thread lock when calling it.

code for debugging:
Python code

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import threading
import time
from random import randint

class webSocketServer:

    INSTANCE = None
    ADDR = "127.0.0.1"
    PORT = 7001

    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = {}
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def addClient(self, client):
        async with self.lock:
            client.lock = threading.Lock()
            self.clients[client.id] = client
            return self.clients[client.id]

    async def removeClient(self, client):
        async with self.lock:
            if client.id in self.clients:
                del self.clients[client.id]

    async def handle_client(self, client):
        client = await self.addClient(client)
        while True:
            try:
                packet = await client.recv()
                print("Packet received", packet)
            except Exception as e:
                break
        await self.removeClient(client)

    def run(self):
        server = websockets.serve(self.handle_client, webSocketServer.ADDR, webSocketServer.PORT, loop=self.loop)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(server)
        self.loop.run_forever()


def notifyClients(webSocketServer):
    while True:
        for id in webSocketServer.clients:
            client = webSocketServer.clients[id]
            with client.lock:
                loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                loop.run_until_complete(send_message(client))
                print(str(threading.current_thread().ident), "finished!")
        time.sleep(randint(1, 3))

async def send_message(client):
    print("Lock acquired... trying to send message")
    try:
        await client.send(str(threading.current_thread().ident)+" say hi")
        print("Message sent")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occured", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    webSocketServer = webSocketServer()
    webSocket_thread = threading.Thread(target = webSocketServer.run)
    webSocket_thread.start()
    print("Running...")

    for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=notifyClients, args=(webSocketServer,))
        t.start()
```

html code

```
    <body>
        <script>
            function initSocket() {
                var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:7001');
                socket.addEventListener('open', function(event) {
                    socket.send("Connection open");
                });
                socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
                    console.log(event.data);
                });
                socket.addEventListener("close", function(event) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        initSocket();
                    }, 1000); // try to recreate socket in 1 second
                });
            }
            initSocket();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've thought of creating a queue and make a task on the WebsocketServer that perform tasks from the Queue.
I saw that asyncio have also a Queue option but it again requires an async function to perform it.. so I'll end up in the same situation.

Is there any option of making this communication without relaying on the event loop?
What is the right approach for this kind of situation ?
Is there a way for make a communication between two different event loops on different threads?

--- edit ---
I've added code for debugging above ^
It demonstrate the same environment and basically what I'm trying to achieve.

You can see that the javascript code hangs when receiving a message from the Websocket server...
but if we uses the asyncio event loop from the WebsocketServer handle_client function it will work smooth.

python code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import threading
import time
from random import randint

class webSocketServer:

    INSTANCE = None
    ADDR = "127.0.0.1"
    PORT = 7001

    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = {}
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def addClient(self, client):
        async with self.lock:
            client.lock = threading.Lock()
            self.clients[client.id] = client
            return self.clients[client.id]

    async def removeClient(self, client):
        async with self.lock:
            if client.id in self.clients:
                del self.clients[client.id]

    async def handle_client(self, client):
        client = await self.addClient(client)
        while True:
            try:
                packet = await client.recv()
                print("Packet received", packet)
                await client.send(packet)
                print("Sending !")
                time.sleep(2)
            except Exception as e:
                break
        await self.removeClient(client)

    def run(self):
        server = websockets.serve(self.handle_client, webSocketServer.ADDR, webSocketServer.PORT, loop=self.loop)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(server)
        self.loop.run_forever()


def notifyClients(webSocketServer):
    while True:
        for id in webSocketServer.clients:
            client = webSocketServer.clients[id]
            with client.lock:
                loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                loop.run_until_complete(send_message(client))
                print(str(threading.current_thread().ident), "finished!")
        time.sleep(randint(1, 3))

async def send_message(client):
    print("Lock acquired... trying to send message")
    try:
        await client.send(str(threading.current_thread().ident)+" say hi")
        print("Message sent")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occured", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    webSocketServer = webSocketServer()
    webSocket_thread = threading.Thread(target = webSocketServer.run)
    webSocket_thread.start()
    print("Running...")

    # for i in range(3):
    #     t = threading.Thread(target=notifyClients, args=(webSocketServer,))
    #     t.start()
```

html code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function initSocket() {
                var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:7001');
                socket.addEventListener('open', function(event) {
                    socket.send("Connection open");
                });
                socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
                    console.log(event.data);
                    socket.send(event.data);
                });
                socket.addEventListener("close", function(event) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        initSocket();
                    }, 1000); // try to recreate socket in 1 second
                });
            }
            initSocket();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AhmedAEK thanks a lot for your response! I understand what you're saying. The problem is that the code is pretty big that's why I extracted the lines that I think that are mostly relevant. I'll build a small code with the same structure and share for the debugging

Comment: @AhmedAEK added example code. It demonstrate exactly my needs

Comment: both code snippets work without any problem ... python3.9

Comment: @AhmedAEK check on the javascript console. you will not receive the messages events in time. it will take the website websockets a lot of time before receiving them. And I wonder even if it just in my end. is this example is the right approach ?

Comment: the code works fine here, but this is not the optimal way to use a lock, as you are blocking the main thread loop, consider making the lock async so the main loop won't be blocked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63420413/how-to-use-threading-lock-in-async-function-while-object-can-be-accessed-from-mu

Comment: @AhmedAEK The problem with async lock is that is not thread safe and I can't use it in synchronized functions and has to run within the same loop. I can't use it in two different loops as I did In the above example code

Comment: the linked answer makes a threadsafe and asyncio safe Lock that doesn't block asyncio thread but instead returns it to the eventloop temporarily until the lock is acquirable, this is still a threadlock ... use its content.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Thanks a lot mate :) Will try it and notify you how it went

Comment: `Websockets.__init__` executes in the main thread.  So you create `self.lock` in the main thread.  But `Websockets.run` executes in the secondary thread, and therefore so does `handle_client`, `add_client` and `remove_client`.  So you cannot access `self.lock` in those functions.  BTW there are asyncio functions for developing cross-threaded programs: `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`, `asyncio.to_thread` (py3.10+), `loop.call_soon_threadsafe`, and `loop.run_in_executor`.